# How to add Bindings to TIdTCPServer at runtime?

Tags: networking, c++builder, indy

Working with TIdTCPServer and it's working cool. Binding that I added to it was using it's property via ui property Object Insp ....It's ok for now,but when I need to deploy this app on other computer it's necessary to add bindings at runtime.

How can I do this?

I googled and found lots of links but in delphi!

the way i did:

```
serv->Bindings->Items[0]->IP="192.168.1.200";
serv->Bindings->Items[0]->Port=5089;
```

but it refuses to run without errors!

Comment: Actually It's working ! By adding serv->StartListening();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bindings collection has an `Add()` method, eg:

```
TIdSocketHandle *Binding = serv->Bindings->Add();
Binding->IP = ...;
Binding->Port = ...;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
tserver.Bindings.Add.IP := '192.168.2.2';
tserver.Bindings.Add.Port := 3545;
tserver.Active := true;
```

Comment: This adds 2 bindings: 1st with IP 192.168.2.2 and Port 0, 2nd with empty IP and Port 3545. The result my still seem to work, as the 2nd binding will default to listening on localhost. But anyway, its bad idea.